# WPF MVVM Editable Combobox new value is null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Tried all the solutions for similar issues around here, still no go. I have a `ComboBox` that should work for selection of existing items and/or for adding new ones. Only the selected item part works. Category is just an object with a `Name` and `Id`.

Thanks in advance!

`XAML`

```
<ComboBox Name="CbCategory" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Text="{Binding NewCategory.Name}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    IsEditable="True"/>
```

`Code behind`

```
private Category _selectedCategory;

public Category SelectedCategory
{
    get { return _selectedCategory; }

    set
    {
        if (Equals(_selectedCategory, value)) return;
        _selectedCategory = value;
        SendPropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
    }
}

private Category _newCategory;

public Category NewCategory
{
    get { return _newCategory; }

    set
    {
         if (Equals(_newCategory, value)) return;
         _newCategory = value;
          SendPropertyChanged("NewCategory");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Text` Binding doesn't work because you're binding against a `null` `Category` property. Instantiate it instead.

```
public Category NewCategory
{
    get { return _newCategory ?? (_newCategory = new Category()); }
    set
        {
          if (Equals(_newCategory, value)) return;
          _newCategory = value;
           SendPropertyChanged("NewCategory");
         }
}
```

**Edit:** Elaborating as per your comment:

Your `ComboBox.Text` binding is set to `"{Binding NewCategory.Name}"`, so no matter what the value of `SelectedCategory` is, the `Text` property will always reflect the name of the `NewCategory`.

When `NewCategory` is null, the `Text` property has nothing to bind to, and therefore the 2-way binding cannot be executed (that is, the value of the `Text` property cannot be passed back to `NewCategory.Name`, because that will cause an `NullReferenceException` (because the `NewCategory` is null).

This does not affect the case of the `SelectedItem`, because that's binding directly to the `SelectedCategory` property, and not a sub-property of that.

Comment: whicked! it's working... but I just want to understand why? I mean, in selectedCategory is not instantiated either, yet it works... could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Create new varible to keep text of combobox. If the selectedItem having null value get the text of combobox as new Item,

Code :

```
<ComboBox Name="CbCategory" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Text="{Binding Name}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    IsEditable="True"/>

private String _name;
public Category Name
{
    get { return _name; }

    set
    {        
         _name = value
         SendPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}

public ICommand ItemChange
{
 get
 {
   `return new RelayCommand(() =>`{
                    try{string item = this.SelectedCategory.Code;}
catch(Exception ex){string item = this.Name;}
                }, () => { return true; });
            }
        }
```